# How to write SQL query for yii2 ? "InnerJoin"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mongodb, yii2

SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM bd.group 
INNER JOIN bd.account2group ON bd.group.id = bd.account2group.group_id 
INNER JOIN bd.account ON bd.account2group.account_id = bd.account.id
WHERE bd.group.id = 8
```

How will it be in yii2?

Comment: which db you used mysql or mongo? you have to share more information

Comment: You will find what do you want in the documentation of [yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder)

Comment: Zaynul Abadin Tuhin, I use MongoDB.

Comment: If you have ready to use SQL, you may just use `Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get to this query using Yii2. You should probably be able to get to all these solutions by reading the docs. At https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en the 'Working with databases' should give you more than enough examples to get at least something working.

If you want to use the QueryBuilder from Yii2 it will look like this:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query)
    ->from('bd.group')
    ->innerJoin('bd.account2group', 'bd.group.id = bd.account2group.group_id')
    ->innerJoin('bd.account', 'bd.account2group.account_id = bd.account.id')
    ->where([
        'bd.group.id' => 8,
    ]);
```

Then you can call `$query->all()`, `$query->one()`, or one of the other functions that the `Query` class holds. Check out https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query for all possible options.